# How To Access (Named) Modules In RequireJS?

Tags: module, coffeescript, requirejs

How can I access a (named) module with RequireJS?

Let's say this is my module (**sayings/sayings-list.coffee**):

```
define 'saySomething', [], ->
  alert 'something'
```

My main file (**main.coffee**) looks like this:

```
require ['sayings/sayings-list'], (sayings) ->
  sayings.saySomething()
```

Now I want to send a variable back and forth! Something like:

```
require ['sayings/sayings-list'], (sayings) ->
  sayings.saySomething(text)
```

How would this be **reflected** in my module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General rule: you should use anonymous `define` calls rather than named `define` calls and let the optimizer (`r.js` or other optimizer that understand the AMD spec) add names when it optimizes your modules into a bundle. There are rare exceptions to this rule but what you show here is not an exception.

If you must use a named module you should structure it like this:

```
define 'saySomething', [], -> 
  saySomething: (text) -> alert text
```

So that it exports a function accessible as `saySomething`. Note that the module name and the name of the exported function could be different.

Then you must load it using its name:

```
require ['saySomething'], (sayings) ->
  sayings.saySomething(text)
```

And you'll have to set your configuration to give a path that maps the name of the module to the file that contains it. This is necessary because by adding the name to the `define` call, you've decoupled the module name from the file name. So you have to tell RequireJS how to find the module.

```
require.config
  paths:
    saySomething: "sayings/sayings-list"
```

Comment: Thank you! In case I don't assign a name to the module, the last configuration part is not needed?

Comment: That's right. That specific piece of configuration is not needed if you do not specify a name as the first argument to `define` because then the path to the module is used (minus the `.js` extension) to make the module name (which would be `sayings/sayings-list`). So when you use it, you'd do `require ['sayings/sayings-list'], (sayings) ->`